# Having problems with implementing the center slider using the slick slider from Ken Wheeler

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I am having a lot of problems with being able to use the center mode slider to implement within my website. It seems that the arrow next and previous do not seem to appear. Has anyone successfully been able to use this slider ?

It is from this website:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have the problem, but I decided to write this down to also help others.

The issue might be that your background color is set to white (and so are the arrows). If you still can't see them, try applying a padding on the parent element.

```
body { background-color: #eee; padding: 0 25px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26bx0e1g/

Hope this helps!